# How to setup TensorFlow for use with GPU

Tags: tensorflow, installation, deep-learning, gpu, cudnn

I want to install TensorFlow with support for my GPU. I have a GeForce GTX 4070 GPU. It has a compute capability of 8.9 which is more than  enough.
I tried to install tensorflow with:
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]

But when I verify the GPU support the list is empty:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

I have installed NVIDIA® GPU drivers, CUDA® Toolkit 11.8 and cuDNN SDK 8.6.0.
Please is there someone who knows this issue and can help me?

I'm using Windows 10.
Besides my issue is it possible to get GPU support working on Windows 10?

The following error information I get each time:

2024-03-09 21:29:34.106076: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.106172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2024-03-09 21:29:34.986368: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.986691: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.986909: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.987114: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.987306: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.987496: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.987682: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.987872: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2024-03-09 21:29:34.987894: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]

Comment: You've most likely missed some required dependency. Your question has very few details to be able to help you.

Comment: You might have better luck here: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/

Comment: Now I have the correct versions and also conda installed but I get the same error (a couple of .dll files are missing)

Comment: As of Tensorflow 2.10 there is no CUDA support on Windows. Please take the time to check release notes

Comment: I finally managed, after a few days, to get the GPU support working for TensorFlow in Keras4Delphi. First the versions for CPU: Python 3.12 (64 bit) and TensorFlow 2.16.1. And for GPU: Python 3.10 (64 bit) and TensorFlow 2.10.0. I found the following video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KinTNHO-6IY    
Finally I used the following command: pip install --user install tensorflow==2.10.0 (in cmd.exe)

Comment: I just wanted to share this, thanks for your thoughts